# What is a cordwainer, with regard to Waterdeep's "Most Diligent League of Sail-makers and Cordwainers"?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist

One of Waterdeep's many guilds is the Most Diligent League of Sail-makers and Cordwainers (listed in the [introduction to *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/introduction#GuildMembership), p. 13). **What is a cordwainer in this context?**

[Merriam-Webster defines a cordwainer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cordwainer) as a shoemaker, or a worker in Cordovan leather (archaic). [Wikipedia has an article on cordwainers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer) in the shoemaker sense.

But Waterdeep already has an Order of Cobblers and Corvisers, and a League of Skinners and Tanners. Cordwainers are in a guild together with sail-makers, so it stands to reason that they would have some sort of connection to sail making.

Any D&D/Forgotten Realms source is acceptable.

Comment: A related question by you: [What is a joiner, with regard to Waterdeep's “Fellowship of Salters, Packers, and Joiners”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169788/what-is-a-joiner-with-regard-to-waterdeeps-fellowship-of-salters-packers-an)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### A mistake

My guess is that the author thought cordwainer was a synonym for ropemaker - a cord is a thin rope and the author mistakenly thought that cordwainer was a maker of cords rather than (leather) shoes. [Inconceivable](https://youtu.be/dTRKCXC0JFg). If so, it’s a lesson to always check the dictionary before using unfamiliar words.

Given that sailmakers use canvas from hemp to make sails for ships, whereas cordwainers use leather from [Córdoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3rdoba,_Spain) to make shoes - and ships don’t have feet - there seems to be no sensible reason why they are together.

Historically, there is a distinction between [cordwainers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer) and cobblers. Cordwainers made shoes from new leather, cobblers repaired shoes and made new shoes from recycled leather. This distinction was so deep that they formed different guilds.

Comment: And Corvisers was pretty much a synonym for Cordwainers. On the other hand, Ropewalkers can mean both acrobats and rope makers, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ropewalk

Comment: You are probably correct. If you like, you can add that the 2e boxed set *City of Splendors* indeed talks about only sails and ropes in the detailed description of *The Most Diligent League of Sail-makers and Cordwainers*.

Comment: @ZwiQ: I'd suggest leaving that as your own answer, including the relevant quotes/paraphrasing. :)

Comment: @Mołot:  I think "roper" is/was much more common than "ropewalker" for the sense of someone who makes ropes.  In fact, "ropewalker" doesn't appear in that Wikipedia article, and the OED entry for "rope-walker" only has the sense of "acrobat".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sure, but in D&D a roper is something *totally* different. I am absolutely certain I would not want a roper involved in sailmaking. Well... unless it was a really smart one, then hundred-foot "arm" span might be useful... Hrmmm...